# C++11 Chrono - How to cast 'unsigned int' to a time_point<system_clock>?

Tags: c++11, c++-chrono

I have a function that has this signature:

```
void checkTime (const std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> &time)
{
   //do stuff...
}
```

I need to call the above function like this:

```
void wait_some_time (unsigned int ms)
{
    //do stuff...
    checkTime(ms); //ERROR: How can I cast unsigned int to a time_point<system_clock> as now() + some milliseconds?
    //do more stuff...
}
```

I want to use like this:

```
wait_some_time(200); //wait now + 200ms
```

**Question:**

**How can I cast 'unsigned int' to a const std::chrono::time_point that has the milliseconds value ?**

Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, but I completely cannot understand what are you after. What is "*time point that has the milliseconds value*"? How do you define such a cast? I mean, your question looks like "-What time it is (`time_point`)? - 500ms (your `uint`)." From your code it's hard to derive, whether you want to check time, or wait for some time. Those are two different things to me. What does check time is supposed to do?

Comment: You can cast it in a few ways. The question is how do you want to pass a duration into a function that expects a `time_point` (e.g. a duration since epoch)? What would be the semantics?

Comment: I'm sorry...it is from now + 200ms for example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I cast 'unsigned int' to a const std::chrono::time_point that has the milliseconds value ?

A `time_point` is a point in time, represented as an offset to some epoch (the "zero" value for the time_point). For `system_clock` the epoch is 00:00:00 Jan 1 1970.

Your `unsigned int` is just an offset, it can't be converted directly to a `time_point` because it has no epoch information associated with it.

So to answer the question "how do you convert an `unsigned int` to a `time_point`?" you need to know what the `unsigned int` represents. The number of seconds since the epoch started? The number of hours since you last called the function? A number of minutes from now?

If what it's meant to mean is "now + N milliseconds" then N corresponds to a `duration`, measured in units of milliseconds. You can convert it to that easily with `std::chrono::milliseconds(ms)` (where the type `milliseconds` is a typedef for something like `std::chrono::duration<long long, std::milli>` i.e. a duration represented as a signed integer type in units of 1000th of a second).

Then to get the time_point corresponding to "now + N milliseconds" you  just add that `duration` to a `time_point` value for "now" obtained from the relevant clock:

```
    std::chrono::system_clock::now() + std::chrono::milliseconds(ms);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a `time_pont` with a `duration`, and you can construct a `duration` with `unsigned int`, so

```
using TimePoint = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock>; 
using Duration = std::chrono::duration<unsigned int, std::milli>;
checkTime(TimePoint(Duration(ms)));
```

... although I don't really see what you want to achieve :)

EDIT: If you want now + ms, you can write

```
std::chrono::system_clock::now() + Duration(ms)
```

Comment: Your second typedef could be replaced by `std::chrono::milliseconds`

Comment: And this will give the wrong answer, it will be 200ms from Jan 1 1970, not 200ms from now.

Comment: @JonathanWakely You cannot use `std::chrono::milliseconds`, as it is signed, and we want unsigned. As for the answer, when I wrote this, it wasn't clarified what the epoch was the questioner wanted. I'll edit it accordingly...

Comment: The variable `ms` is unsigned, but why does it matter whether it is converted to a duration with a signed representation or an unsigned representation? It still represents the same number of milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C++14 you can simplify it by using [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/operator%22%22ms)

```
auto later = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + 500ms;
```

But even without 14 I would alter your function definition to:

```
void wait_some_time (std::chrono::milliseconds ms);
```

and then just add the milliseconds to your steady_clock.
If you really want to support an integer, you could implement the operator by yourself (see cppreference for the original source)

```
constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds operator ""ms(unsigned long long ms)
{
    return chrono::milliseconds(ms);
}
```